# rokoko plugin armature not parented correctly

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I download a character as a T pose went to blender and opened rokoko plugin. I have an armature animation already animation so I wanted to add my character to this armature so my character applied to this armature animation , but every time I Try to retarget the character , the arms looks weird and kind of glitchy. I just need help with this thank you

[image]

[image]

blender file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1de7j_bRY0SS96vUBbiIlpeXGQtXq44K0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the arm bone orientation needs to be corrected in *Edit* mode: Select the left arm and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>90</kbd>, select the right arm and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>-90</kbd>. Also make sure that this new orientation doesn't mess up the other actions. If this is the case then you'll need to correct the rotation of the bone in *Pose* mode in the *Graph Editor*.